# FullCalendar Event Resize count

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Hello Stackoverflow,

I using the external drag and drop feature in FullCalendar. I have a situation where I have two different kinds of events and I wish to calculate IF the user re-size the event from one to whatever from the day placed using drag and drop how to calculate how many days it resized.

Here is my js code

```
$(document).ready(function() {


/* initialize the external events
-----------------------------------------------------------------*/

$('#external-events div.external-event').each(function() {

//Do a check to see which class was select and assign bg color with the color of that resource
if($(this).text() == "Birthday"){
    bgColor = '#3A87AD'
}
else if($(this).text() == "Holiday"){
    bgColor = '#A53333'
}
// create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
// it doesn't need to have a start or end
var eventObject = {
title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
backgroundColor: bgColor
};

// store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
$(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

// make the event draggable using jQuery UI
$(this).draggable({
    zIndex: 999,
revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
});

});


/* initialize the calendar
-----------------------------------------------------------------*/

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        right: 'title'
    },
    editable: true,
droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
drop: function(date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

//Minus vacation days
$('#vacation_days').text($('#vacation_days').text() - 1);

// retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

// we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

// assign it the date that was reported
copiedEventObject.start = date;
copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

// render the event on the calendar
// the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

// is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
// if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
$(this).remove();
}

}
});


});
```

Comment: I would love to solve your problem, could you make a jsFiddle, so everyone can understand what is going on in your code ?

Comment: I think you can solve using eventResize; take a look at my answer for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`eventResize`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventResize/) event of FullCalendar, it is:

> Triggered when resizing stops and the event has changed in duration

Code:

```
eventResize: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) {

    alert(
        "The end date of " + event.title + "has been moved " + dayDelta + " days and " + minuteDelta + " minutes.");

    if (!confirm("is this okay?")) {
        revertFunc();
    }

}
```

Working demo: <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>